# Copy and modify solutions (with setup projects) in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, setup-project

I have a solution here, that consists of 13 projects and 2 setup projects in VS2008.

I need to create another solution for this, as each solution is gonna be for each version (v1 and v2 of my project).
I also need to update the setup project, as each one will have its own files.

How can I do this? 
I'm not sure whether copy - paste - modification will be the best solution, as I had problems before with the `HRESULT = '80004005'` error and which made me lose like 8 hours of work..

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to issue either a branch (if v1 and v2 are related and you'd like to be able to merge changes from one into the other) or a copy (if they are going to be completely unrelated products), then download the solution from the branch or copy directory into a new location.

If you want users to be able to install both v1 and v2 at the same time, you'll need to generate a new upgrade code for the setup project. If you want the installation of v2 to overwrite v1, then ensure that the product codes are the different but the upgrade code is the same.

Comment: well they should be independent from each other

Comment: @noloman: This should provide you with whatever information you need for both scenarios. Let me know if you have additional questions.